# Google Analytics API: segment for event condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics Google Spreadsheets plugin.

I'd like to segment data to only include visitors who have an event action of "get started" against them.

Here is what I tried when I try to run the report Google Sheets says the syntax is invalid:

```
segment=users::condition::ga:eventAction=@started
```

Then tried:

```
segment=users::condition::ga:eventAction==get started
```

Then tried:

```
segment=users::condition::ga:eventAction=="get started"
```

How do I tell the Google-Analytics API to return only users who have triggered the event action "get started"?

I'm not sure if I'm close or not. I suspect it might have something to do with the space between "get" and "started". But if that was the case maybe the attempt using =@ would have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your first example will work once you remove the "segment=" part of the string.

Comment: You can also create the segment in the GA UI, and then get the ID of the segment here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list The ID can be populated directly into the segment cell - it will look like "gaid::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: Did this work? If so, feel free to mark as answer ;)